# Unable to get response from grid gain on jenkins while unlocking the nodes

Tags: gridgain

While running jobs thorugh jenkins server, which basically sending request to one of the grid gain node for tests execution. The tests gets executed successfully, but when its trying to unlock the nodes it gets hanged. Its not getting respons from grid gain. No detail logs either on grid gain or jenkins. It started happening the time I upgraded jenkins and java to 1.7. The tomcat and grid gain kept on existing (old) version.

Gridgain ver: 2.1.1
Apache Tomcat: apache-tomcat-6.0.24
Jenkins: 1.549

Answer (score 0):

GridGain v.2.1.1 was not tested against Java 1.7, it also has been a while since that version was released. You should upgrade to the [latest version](http://www.gridgain.org/download/) of GridGain which was released under Apache 2.0 license (current GridGain version is 6.0.1)